# Minimizing python function that has numpy array as argument

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm new to python, and I have the following problem: I am trying to minimize a python function that has a numpy array as one of its arguments. When I use scipy.optimize.fmin, it turns my array into a list (which results in the function failing to evaluate). Is there an optimization function that does accept numpy arrays as function arguments?

Thanks in advance!

-MB

Edit: Here is an example of what I'm talking about, courtesy of @EOL:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np

def rosen(x):
    print x
    x=x[0]
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)
x0 = np.array([[1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2]])
xopt = optimize.fmin(rosen, x0, xtol=1e-8, disp=True)
#[ 1.3  0.7  0.8  1.9  1.2]
#(note that this used to be a numpy array of length 0, 
#now it's "lost" a set of brackets")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using `optimize.fmin` which comes from the [scipy tutorial](http://www.tau.ac.il/~kineret/amit/scipy_tutorial/):

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
def rosen(x):
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)
x0 = [1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2]
xopt = optimize.fmin(rosen, x0, xtol=1e-8, disp=True)
# Optimization terminated successfully.
#          Current function value: 0.000000
#          Iterations: 339
#          Function evaluations: 571
print(xopt)
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

Does this help? If not, can you modify this example to show what is turning into a list?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My problem is that I need (well, it has been convenient so far) to use a numpy array as the input to my function. If I understand the lingo correctly, your function uses a list. I've changed your code to demonstrate what happens to me:

import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np

def rosen(x):
    print x
    x=x[0]
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)
x0 = np.array([[1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2]])
xopt = optimize.fmin(rosen, x0, xtol=1e-8, disp=True)

print(xopt)

Comment: Sorry, that looks insane! I'll reformat and add an edit to my original post.

Comment: I think the problem occurs if you modify the shape of the input `x`. If you need to modify `x`, instead may a copy: `y=x.copy()`. Then do the computations on `y`.